# What happens in Microsoft SQL Server 2012 .ldf when the database log file if full?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Recently we found out that `.ldf` file of our  Microsoft SQL Server 2012 database was growing large. We have set limit as follows:

[image: screenshot]

Now we have a question: What will happen when log `.ldf` file reaches its size limit?

Thank you

Comment: Have you already reviewed the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/logs/troubleshoot-a-full-transaction-log-sql-server-error-9002?view=sql-server-2017)? It discusses possible responses to a full transaction log and suggests how to avoid it in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the log is full, your database will fail any transaction that requires something written to the log (insert,update,delete, schema change, etc.).

From your screenshot, are you really planning to limit it to 15MB? How big is the database? How big is the largest table in the database? You also mention that it is growing very large. How do you define very large?

Generally speaking, you need your log file to be at least as big as your largest index, so that if you rebuild it, it won't fail. If the log has grown, then that's usually because you need a bigger log file. The only time you'd want to shrink the log file is if you know that a 1 off operation happened that will never happen again (e.g. some sort of data load/export). If your log file is growing significantly larger than your data files, you may want to check your recovery model - if it's full then you need to be taking log backups.

Comment: Thank you for response. I have searched on the internet, but still not sure: what recovery models are available and what is the difference between them?

Comment: @TornikeShavishvili This is strange, there are *only* 3 recovery models full,simple and bulk logged. Recovery model only control logging and does not controls size of the log file. Please read [This](https://www.sqlshack.com/understanding-database-recovery-models/)

Comment: @TornikeShavishvili, having a recovery plan to meet your RPO will determine the needed log size, recovery model, and backups. This is arguably the most important DBA responsibility so it is very important to understand and test your recovery plan.

Answer (score 1):

> Now we have a question: what will happen when log .ldf file reaches its size limit?

Let me start by saying that keeping 15mb as log file limit is pure blunder. I never advocate putting limit on transaction log file size, instead ask users to focus on [Better Transaction Log Management](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/importance-of-proper-transaction-log-size-management/).

When maximum size of log file restriction is reached log file cannot grow so transactions cannot happen and application would start giving exceptions or would simply fail. This can also lead to database going into recovery state which means users cannot access database at all.

Comment: Without a cap, one log file can fill a drive if not properly managed, potentially preventing other log files on that drive from expanding as needed.  I'd rather have one db hit the cap than all of them be at risk.  If I weren't managing my drives and files :)

Comment: @Kevin3NF I would rather manager transaction log properly than allow application to fail and database to go in recovery with log file restriction.